Создать папочную структуру на гитхаб
Нужна помощь по гиту и гитхабу.Я прохожу курс обучения с проверяющим,данный курс состоит из нескольких уроков,с домашними заданиями,которые надо пушить на гитхаб.Курс начинается с того,что Нужно в диске д создать "папку проекта",в ней создаются в процессе"папки уроков"(lesson1 lesson2 3 итд),а в папках уроков сохраняются джава классы из sublime text(Я пользуюсь не ide.)
До определенного момента,я пушил файлы.java,на свой гитхаб,напрямую,но теперь,проверяющий требует "папочную структуру"(покажу скрин).
При попытке запушить целую папку lesson1, возникает ошибка. Как ее решить?Как создать папочную структуру?Помогите,пожалуйста.
D:\startjava\Lesson1 (master -> origin)
λ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/pav1222/startjava.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/pav1222/startjava.git (push)

D:\startjava\Lesson1 (master -> origin)
λ git add "Lesson1"
fatal: pathspec 'Lesson1' did not match any files

D:\startjava\Lesson1 (master -> origin)
λ git add "Lesson1/"
fatal: pathspec 'Lesson1/' did not match any files

D:\startjava\Lesson1 (master -> origin)
λ git add Lesson1
fatal: pathspec 'Lesson1' did not match any files
                





1 скрин-как должно быть на гитхабе,2 скрин-структура проекта,3 скрин-как это у меня сейчас.

Ты не пробовал почитать какую нибудь инструкцию по гиту? Попробуй.

git add . это значит добавить текущую папку, либо в корневой папке проекта git add Lesson1, добавить файл, либо папку Lesson1

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_examples

Конечно пробовал читать инструкции,но ошибки то возникают

@ПавелМиронов, здравствуйте!  Какой смысл отвечать на ваши вопросы, если вы не можете их принять?

Если вы находитесь в директории D:\startjava\Lesson1 и пытаетесь выполнить команду git add Lesson1, почему вас удивляет ошибка fatal: pathspec 'Lesson1' did not match any files.  Вы же буквально пытаетесь добавить локальную вложенную директорию Lesson1\Lesson1, которой у вас нет.

Что значит принять?Мне ставят минусы,и я не могу создавать темы.

@ПавелМиронов, "принять ответ" значит поставить зелёную галочку, как вы сделали с ответом на свой вопрос Поиск одинаковых цифр в сотнях

Помогите с компиляцией,пожалуйста.

Git по своей природе не может хранить папки без файлов внутри. Чтоб обойти это ограничение нужно добавить в папку какой-либо файл. По ряду причин хорошим тоном считается, чтоб этот файл начинался с .git. Это может быть служебный для самого git файл .gitattributes или .gitignore или вообще пустой файл, который чаще всего называют .gitkeep
